# How can I find, but not decode, BASE64 entries in an LDAP?

Tags: bash, perl, ldap, base64

I have a rather large ODSEE LDAP that I need to find all base64 entries inside of. I do not need to decode them, merely find them. The majority of them are the result of bad data entry, such as a leading or trailing space.

I've tried to find some code examples online, but everything I've found is how to decode the entries when encountered. Since decoding them would make the error harder to spot (is there a trailing space there? Can't tell!) I need to avoid that.

I would prefer bash or perl answers. I'm limited on what perl modules I can use however due to restrictions placed by upper management.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have access to the LDIF file?

Comment: I'm sorry for not replying sooner; I didn't see this comment hiding up here.
I was still in the researching stage and hadn't tried anything yet. It's the entire LDAP database, not just one LDIF. But, it looks like I'm onto an answer below. Thanks for chiming in! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `slapcat` to dump a copy of the database somewhere, and then `grep` inside that file for double colons `::`. For example:

```
dn: [...]
userPassword:: e1NBU0x9amhhbGxlcg==
objectClass: inetLocalMailRecipient
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
```

In this example you can see that the password is base64 encoded, since it has a double colon. The `dn` value tells you which object that is for of course.

Comment: I had noticed the double colon but didn't know if that was consistent with base64 entries in the LDAP or just an artifact of the data entry error.
I doubt I could dump the entire database, but maybe I could write a script to cycle through it looking for that...

Comment: Yes, the great internets will tell you :: means base64. Rather than dumping the entire db, something simple like this will at least get you dns: `slapcat [...] | awk '/^dn/ {dn=$0} /::/ {print dn "\n" $0}'`

Comment: It seems I don't have slapcat on the system and, of course, I can't install it. But, it looks like I can get a similar, if slower, result by repeatedly searching the LDAP with ldapsearch.

Comment: I wrote a perl script that pulls all the DNs from all the OUs, and then searches all of them, grepping for ::. Getting a nice CSV of all of the errors. Thanks for the :: hint! :-)